# Uploading multiple Files only works if all files are selected at once

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, files

I am have an aura component where user are uploading files on a SF Site form.
The files are not saved until the Form is submitted an the record is saved.
If I select multiple files at one time all the files displays as being selected and rendering correctly.
But if I select a file and then go to select another the original file is replaced by the new one.
How can I accommodate both options?

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="fileList" type="Attachment[]" />
<aura:attribute name="fileNames" type="String" />


<lightning:input type="file" label="" name="file" multiple="true" onchange=" 
     {!c.handleFilesChange}" />

<br />
Files Selected: {!v.fileNames}
```

Controller JS

```
closeModal: function(component, event, helper) {
  document.getElementById("messageModal").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("backGroundId").style.display = "none";
},  

var fileList = [];

handleFilesChange: function(component, event, helper) {
  var files = event.getSource().get("v.files");
  var fileNames;

  for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (fileNames == null) {
      fileNames = files[i].name;
    } else {
      fileNames += ", " + files[i].name;
    }
  }

  component.set("v.fileNames", fileNames);
  component.set("v.fileList", fileList);

  [...files].forEach(file => {
    let fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = function() {
      let fileContents = fileReader.result;
      let base64Mark = "base64,";
      let dataStart = fileContents.indexOf(base64Mark) + base64Mark.length;
      fileContents = fileContents.substring(dataStart);
      let base64Data = encodeURIComponent(fileContents);

      fileList.push({ fileName: file.name, base64Data: base64Data });
      console.log(JSON.stringify(fileList));
      component.set("v.fileList", fileList);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to pull your var `filelist = [];` outside of the scope.

Right now, you are saying, the first time you select files - Hey, select these files then create a new array then do something with it.

In this same example, say you go and select one file, it's going to effectively say, "Ok, select this file, then create a new array, then do something with it. Awesome!"

but then you realize you need a new file, it's going to say, "Ok, let's select this new file, create a new empty array, then I will do something with it, great!"

Bring the new array outside that function scope like so:

```
var fileList = [];

handleFilesChange: function(component, event, helper) {
  var files = event.getSource().get("v.files");
  var fileNames;

  for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (fileNames == null) {
      fileNames = files[i].name;
    } else {
      fileNames += ", " + files[i].name;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.  I though that variables have to be declared within the scope.  Moving the variable gives an error.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: "message": "c.formTrackerComponent: Failed to parse CONTROLLER for js://c.FormTrackerComponent: org.auraframework.util.json.JsonStreamReader$JsonStreamParseException: Expected ':' [136, 9]: 'fileList' (136:9)"